# I want to append the rows of a dataframe as columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, col

I have several small dataframes such as:

```
name   x   y  z
A      1   2  3
A      1   23  4
A      3    5   6
B       0    2  3
```

And I want to append all the "A"s such that I get this dataframe

```
name    x    y   z   x2   y2 z2    x3   y3   z3
A         1   2  3    1    23 4    3    5     6
B         0  2  3    NaN-------------------> NaN
```

Any help would be appreciated, sorry if the above tables aren't spaced out properly

Answer (score 2):

More like a `pivot` problem after create the key by `cumcount`--- I am using `unstack` here

```
df['Newkey']=df.groupby('name').cumcount()+1
yourdf=df.set_index(['name','Newkey']).unstack().sort_index(level=1,axis=1)
yourdf.columns=yourdf.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format)
yourdf
Out[20]: 
       x1   y1   z1   x2    y2   z2   x3   y3   z3
name                                              
A     1.0  2.0  3.0  1.0  23.0  4.0  3.0  5.0  6.0
B     0.0  2.0  3.0  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `pivot_table` with some couple of other functions:

```
df['idx'] = df.groupby('name').cumcount()+1
df = df.pivot_table(index='name', columns='idx', values=['x', 'y', 'z'], aggfunc='first')
df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = [f'{x}_{y}' for x,y in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Reproduces:

```
  name  x_1  y_1  z_1  x_2   y_2  z_2  x_3  y_3  z_3
0    A  1.0  2.0  3.0  1.0  23.0  4.0  3.0  5.0  6.0
1    B  0.0  2.0  3.0  NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```